# Using variables declared in another namespace

Tags: clojure

I have a dictionary of words stored in a vector in one ns (ns dictionary.core) and I want to have access the vector in another namespace, for example, (ns clojure-project.core) How should I do it? I have been researching the concept of namespaces for some time and I am still confused as to how I can "import" variables defined in another file into my current project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(ns clojure-project.core
  (:require [dictionary.core :as dict]))

(defn choose-a-word []
  (rand-nth (dict/words)))
```

Namespace declarations have many options, so it can be very confusing! Limiting yourself to the above form is in my opinion good style.

Comment: I keep getting this error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate dictionary/core__init.class or dictionary/core.clj on classpath. This is what my namespace looks like: (ns akarify.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as str])
  (:require [dictionary.core :as dict]))

Comment: Is there a file under src/dictionary/core.clj? Happy to take a look at a github repo if that helps?

Comment: https://github.com/p-adams/dictionary It is a little disorganized as I just created the repo. core.clj and the corpus file are the files for my project.

Comment: Seems a bit confusing. Do you want to use `akarify` or `dictionary` as package names? Stick to just one. Then in the package you can have `core` and `corpus`. So you might end up with `dictionary.core` requiring `dictionary.corpus`.

Comment: Hi Mahmud,
You need your .clj files to be in a src directory. Also the `dictionary.core` namespace must be in a file under src/dictionary/core.cljs (not in corups like it is now).

Comment: I want to use the dictionary.core in my akarify package. Can I just add dictionary.core file to my src/akarify directory?

Comment: The namespace must exactly match the filename/directory. So if you want it under src/akarify/dictionary.clj then the namespace must be akarify.dictionary.

Comment: Okay, that works. To import it into my akarify.core is it better to use "use" or "require" it in the namespace? Not sure which is the proper Clojure way of doing it.

Comment: require is preferable to use, as it is more explicit